# Change the value of the AC button to C

Tags: javascript, dom

The clear button: When we click on any operand button, the value of the button should change from AC to C. When this button is clicked, we clear the form and remove any active class from our operator buttons.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const form = document.getElementById("calc_form");
const operand_btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-type=operand]");
const operator_btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-type=operator]");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

let is_operator = false;
let equation = [];

const remove_active = () => {
  operator_btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.classList.remove("active");
  });
};

operand_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    remove_active();
    if (output.value == "0") {
      output.value = e.target.value;
    } else if (output.value.includes(".")) {
      output.value = output.value + "" + e.target.value.replace(".", "");
    } else if (is_operator) {
      is_operator = false;
      output.value = e.target.value;
    } else {
      output.value = output.value + "" + e.target.value;
    }
  });
});

operator_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    remove_active();
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "%":
        output.value = parseFloat(output.value) / 100;
        break;
      case "invert":
        output.value = parseFloat(output.value) * -1;
        break;
      case "=":
        equation.push(output.value);
        output.value = eval(equation.join(""));
        equation = [];
        break;
      default:
        let last_item = equation[equation.length - 1];
        if (["/", "*", "+", "-"].includes(last_item) && is_operator) {
          equation.pop();
          equation.push(e.target.value);
        } else {
          equation.push(output.value);
          equation.push(e.target.value);
        }
        is_operator = true;
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body { text-align: center; }
button, input { margin: 0.5rem 0.1rem; }
.active { background: #FF8; }
```

```html
<form id="calc_form">
  <input type="text" id="output" />
  <br />
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="3">3</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="6">6</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="7">7</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="0">0</button>
  <br />
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="+">+</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="*">*</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="%">%</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="invert">-1</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="=">=</button>
</form>
```

I tried some ways, but I'm a beginner in JavaScript...

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing any of your code...

Comment: I added basic HTML and CSS to display the UI based on the provided JS. Felps, where is your AC/C button anyways? You did not provide HTML and your JS does not mention the existence of such a button.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please tell us what error you are facing and in which part of the provided code it occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a reset listener:

```js
form.addEventListener("reset", (e) => {
  remove_active();
  form.querySelector('button[type="reset"]').innerText = 'AC';
});
```

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const form = document.getElementById("calc_form");
const operand_btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-type=operand]");
const operator_btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-type=operator]");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

form.addEventListener("reset", (e) => {
  remove_active();
  form.querySelector('button[type="reset"]').innerText = 'AC';
});

let is_operator = false;
let equation = [];

const remove_active = () => {
  operator_btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.classList.remove("active");
  });
};

const handleOperator = (operator) => {
  switch (operator) {
    case "%":
      output.value = parseFloat(output.value) / 100;
      break;
    case "invert":
      output.value = parseFloat(output.value) * -1;
      break;
    case "=":
      equation.push(output.value);
      output.value = eval(equation.join(""));
      equation = [];
      break;
    default:
      let last_item = equation[equation.length - 1];
      if (["/", "*", "+", "-"].includes(last_item) && is_operator) {
        equation.pop();
        equation.push(e.target.value);
      } else {
        equation.push(output.value);
        equation.push(operator);
      }
      is_operator = true;
      break;
  }
};

operand_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    remove_active();
    if (output.value == "0") {
      output.value = e.target.value;
    } else if (output.value.includes(".")) {
      output.value = output.value + "" + e.target.value.replace(".", "");
    } else if (is_operator) {
      is_operator = false;
      output.value = e.target.value;
    } else {
      output.value = output.value + "" + e.target.value;
    }
  });
});

operator_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    remove_active();
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
    form.querySelector('button[type="reset"]').innerText = 'C';
    handleOperator(e.target.value); // Pass-in the value
  });
});
```

```css
body { text-align: center; }
button, input { margin: 0.5rem 0.1rem; }
.active { background: #FF8; }
```

```html
<form id="calc_form">
  <input type="text" id="output" />
  <br />
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="3">3</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="6">6</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="7">7</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operand" value="0">0</button>
  <br />
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="+">+</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="*">*</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="%">%</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="invert">-1</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="operator" value="=">=</button>
  <button type="reset">AC</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a genius. one more doubt, so after I call this event,

operator_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => { remove_active(); e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
form.querySelector('button[type="reset"]').innerText = 'C';

 do i have to declare the switch case again?

Comment: @felps I moved the switch to a `handleOperator` function. See the code above. You can call this wherever you want.